# What is the difference between parser options and environment javascript versions in eslint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

In eslint config, you have two places where you define javascript version you want to be using. I'm not sure what the difference is, references do go in depth about possible options but not what they are used for. Unless I missed it somehow.

Comment: `env` is for the *global variables*, `parserOptions` is for the *syntax*. There's an example right in https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring - if you set the env to ES6, which enables the globals, it automatically sets the parser option too, but *not* vice versa.

Comment: global variables like what. aren't those specific to like node or browser. global variables aren't dependent on what javascript version you're running?

Comment: Promise, for example.

Comment: ok make sense, thanks, quick questions: how can you add support for stage 3 features in eslint.

Comment: I'd recommend further research, tacking extra questions into the comment isn't good form.

Comment: i've been researching for 2 hours. I can't get eslint to accept instanceField attributes in class.

Comment: Then give a [mcve] of the code, the config and the expected and actual outputs.

Comment: so to know what rule disables eslint errors for instance field attributes i need to offer reproducible git repo? I'm not saying it's not working, what should I do? This is more of a informational question, not debugging type.

Comment: If that's your question it's not really a question; ESLint's output generally tells you what rule is causing the warning or error. It's also definitely not the question your post is asking. If it's a parsing problem, that's slightly different. And not necessarily a git repo, just the relevant ESLint config, a code snippet you expect to lint [not ]OK and the unexpected output or errors you're getting instead. This is basic question asking, by 12krep you should know this.

Comment: fair point - it should be separate question with some more details